# Cannot link to Boost library with MSVC: Cannot open file *.lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, boost

I'm using [`CLion`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion) and `CMake` to link with `Boost` and as toolchain I chose the `MSVC` compiler:
[image]

My architecture is configured as `amd64` since I'm running a 64-bit system (the default of `x86` only tries to find the 32-bit versions of `Boost` which I don't want).

Furthermore I compiled the 64-bit libraries using [this](http://informilabs.com/building-boost-32-bit-and-64-bit-libraries-on-windows) guide. I setup my `CMake` file respectively:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/local/boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3/stage/x64/lib")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:/local/boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3/boost")
```

My `main.cpp` compiles just fine but I'm getting a linker error:

```
====================[ Build | BoostTesting | Debug ]============================
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\183.4284.104\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe --build D:\Cpp\BoostTesting\cmake-build-debug --target BoostTesting --
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable BoostTesting.exe
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2017\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1415~1.267\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\BoostTesting.dir\objects1.rsp /out:BoostTesting.exe /implib:BoostTesting.lib /pdb:D:\Cpp\BoostTesting\cmake-build-debug\BoostTesting.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\local\boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3\stage\x64\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_69.lib C:\local\boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3\stage\x64\lib\libboost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_69.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\BoostTesting.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\BoostTesting.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_69.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\183.4284.104\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

When using `x86_amd64` as architecture it also fails to link. The other architectures don't make sense for my PC:
[image]

Using the [pre-compiled binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries) from here also fails to link. How to fix this linking problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting `BOOST_ROOT` in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_69_0_b1_rc3")
```

and using `amd64` as the architecture surprisingly did the trick now. Using `MSVC` with `CMake` is better supported with `Visual Studio` (quite obviously) and linking to `Boost` was no issue anymore. Now the build also works from `CLion` but `Visual Studio` should be preferred until `CLion` maybe gets better `MSVC` integration.